# Xetex compiling not working

Tags: xetex

I am running Opensuse 12.4, with kde 4.8.5. I try to compile a tex file using xelatex, but it always give me this output:

```
restricted \write18 enabled.
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

I don't know what to do,

Thank you,

Comment: This is very general, most probably you screwed up your TeX configuration, or did not install properly. Try to look [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=formatstymy), perhaps it will help you.